# Order two different tables from 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have two separate tables which have nothing in common, so I cannot make any join on them.

What I would like is to intersect their results in such way so that the overall results (table1+table2) are sorted by date.

EG:

```
table1, row1 
table1, row5 
table2, row1
table1, row3 
table2, row7
```

Comment: Not sure but are you looking for something like "Use a union query to combine multiple queries into a single result" ? If yes check this link of Microsoft http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-HA102749627.aspx

Comment: I think you can use `union all` and `order by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by forming a subquery by `union all` and then ordering the result of it.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT field1 AS a, field2 AS b, field3 AS c, fieldn AS date_for_order
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT fieldx AS a, fieldy AS b, fieldz AS c, fieldw AS date_for_order
FROM table2
) joined_tables
ORDER BY date_for_order
```

The important thing is to create the same alias for fields from both tables as is the requirement for UNION.

The result will be:

a | b | c | date_for_order